# Hide NavBar when pageYOffSet = 0

Tags: javascript, php, html

On my site, I have two Navigation Bars, one scrolls up along with the text but the other hides when I scroll up and shows when I scroll down. I just don't know how to make it invisible once it's back to pageYOffset = 0. Anyone knows how, please?

Comment: what code controls showing the menu once you scroll down?  please add some relevant code to your question.

Answer (score 1):

first, *welcome to stackoverflow*!

to know when the offset is at a particular position, you need to listen for the scroll and resize events, try something like:

```
function checkPageOffset() {
    if(window.pageYOffset === 0) {
        // do your menu manipulation here
    }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', checkPageOffset);
window.addEventListener('resize', checkPageOffset);
```

this way, the function runs on each scroll and each resize and only runs code if the offset is 0.  you may prefer to test `window.pageYOffset < someMinimumOffset` instead in case the scroll is not exactly to 0.

as i was getting at with my comment above, chances are there's already code somewhere in your system that's testing if the offset is greater than some threshold in order to display the menu in the first place, really you should just have to add on to that function to hide the menu if that condition is not met.  if you can post that code, we might be able to help you integrate a solution more cleanly with your existing setup.

*edit: incorporate listen for resize as per Tracker1's comment below*

Comment: Should also listen to the resize event as this can also change the scroll position.